# Phonegap application throws error running Android 4.0, but works fine on Android 2.3 and below

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a problem with PhoneGap mobile app running on Android version 4.0.3. I am currently using PhoneGap version 1.5.0. And it works perfectly on Android 2.3 and all the lower versions of Android. However, when I try to run it on Android 4.0 - it throws this dialog error...

Application error - A network error occurred. (file:///android_asset/www/messagedetails.html?Id=29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just try with phonegap 1.9.0 version. Because that phonegap 1.5.0 version build may not supported for android 2.3.3+ versions.

Comment: Thanks a ton :) As of now I have just used Local Storage in PhoneGap 1.5.0 to resolve this problem...Thanks for the useful reply, will surely try with the PhoneGap 1.9.0.

Comment: I am using Child browser plugin for integrating Twitter in my app..When I use 1.9.0 , I am getting Errors in the childbrowser.java file..not finding the child browser plugin (1.9.0 version) for Android..need help to get over this...Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you integrate child browser in your project. Please explain with source code.

Comment: I followed this : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser

Comment: that post updated finally on one year back. Please verify it works on 1.9.0 or not.

Comment: Yep your rite...Verified it does not work :( Did not find any other new version for Child Browser for Android. But it works fine with Version 1.5.0

Comment: Just use PhoneGap 2.3+ and remove the ChildBrowser plugin since newer PhoneGap versions come with InAppBrowser plugin built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Possible that phonegap does network operations on the UI thread. Every network operation on the UI thread causes an exception in Android 4.0 this could be your problem.